# How to delete a notification history from recycleview?

Tags: java, android

I have created a recycleview which display a list of notification history.  Here am using realm database which get notification from onesignal.  I have tried to delete a notification history using "name.remove(getAdapterPosition()) ; " On adapter class.  But it's deleting one time. When I opened the app again it's not get deleted.  What I do?  Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

you have to clear the list that you pass to  your adapter :

```
yourList.clear();
```

and then apply an `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your recycler

```
yourRecycler.notifyDataSetChanged();
```